# Adding pagination to nodes

Tags: paging

I'm using Drupal 7, CKEditor (not wysiwyg module). By default the nodes are not paginated but the client wants to have nodes of certain content-type to be paginated. And wants control of this pagination i.e. set page breaks.

How can I make the nodes to paged? And how can I control it?

P.S. I cannot find any  useful explanation (tutorial) of how drupal pager works, so if you know any, it's highly appreciated to post it here.

Comment: If I read your question correctly, the client wants to be able to turn a node into multiple pages from a body field?  I'm gonna go out on a limb and just say this isn't possible without some REALLY complicated client-side scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 7 you should check out the [smart_paging](http://drupal.org/project/smart_paging) module.  It can auto paginate or the user can sepecify the breaks. There is also integration with the [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module, but unfortunately not the CKEditor module.

As mentioned by Greta the core book module may be of use, but it is really intended for content organized in a hierarchical manner. If the nodes are intended to be independent (e.g. articles), it would be overkill to have to make a new book for each article.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is incredibly easy. Use BOOK content type. Just need to enable Books in core modules. If you already have lots of existing content (to much to copy/paste into book pages), you could add a field for Node Reference and link the pages that way.  Book has all that "pagination" functionality -- as well as local menu/index -- built in. Great solution if you aren't too far along.  At the very least, enable Book module and do a sample to demo for client -- to help you conceive the exact behavior that you want.

By the way, that approach is independent of your WYSIWYG (CKEditor).